# Unable to restore ROS

Tags: amazon-ec2, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Hi I have continuous command running on my server

```
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]
do

   name=`/home/ubuntu/backup$now.zip`

   now=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M)
   realm-backup /var/lib/realm/object-server $name
   aws s3 cp $name s3://tm-ep-realm-backups/

   sleep 900

done
```

That works fine, now I launch new EC2 instance and paste compressed files into `/var/lib/realm/object-server`, but the server doesn't launch, am I missing something?

https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#server-recovery-from-a-backup

Answer (score -1):

The second argument to realm-backup must be an empty directory, not 
a zip file.

You can then zip the directory yourself after realm-backup if you want to.

When you paste the backup files in to the directory of the new server,
you must unzip yourself if you use zip files.
When you start the server, there must be a directory of your Realms, not a zip file.